# Override onBackPressed() method. Back button has to be clicked twice to quit the Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My app looks like this:

```
start activity -> menu -> content -> questionnarie -> questionnarie results
```

From 'questionnarie results' I want to go to 'menu' Activity after clicking at the back button. I used the method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Menu.class));
    finish();
}
```

It works but when I click back button again I am in the same Activity and to go to the start Activity back button has to be pressed twice. How can I make this method work properly?

Comment: removed tag `android-studio`. This tag is used for questions/problems about the Android Studio product. Your question is about Android, not about Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Menu.class));
```

This starts a **new instance** of `Menu`. You want to return to the **existing instance** of `Menu`. To do that, you need this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This tells Android that you want to go back to the existing instance of `Menu`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag and then exit the user according to the flag status. Something like this:

```
boolean pressed = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (pressed) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.pressed = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

// after 2 sec making the `pressed` value `false` as default
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            pressed=false;                       
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```